# Segmentation fault in pg_dump utility from PostgreSQL 9.2.3

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, postgresql-9.2, pg-dump

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.3 in my development board,I am taking backup of database using following command and get segmentation fault.

/bin/pg_dump -U db_admin -t mytable -b -C -Ft MYDB|gzip >/home/mydb.tar.gz

I have analyzed dump core using gdb and found that pg_dump gives segmentation from dopr() function

gdb output

```
(gdb)bt 
#0  0x00429c4c in dopr ()
#1  0x0042acda in pg_sprintf ()
#2  0x004249fc in _tarAddFile ()
#3  0x00424d88 in tarClose ()
#4  0x004259a0 in _CloseArchive ()
#5  0x0041e712 in CloseArchive ()
#6  0x0041862e in main ()
(gdb)
```

Please let me know if anyone found solution for this problem.

Comment: Works fine for me here. Does it work with an empty table? Did you try to isolate which record, if any, causes the problem?

Comment: If There are 250 entries in the table then it is working fine for me but if the entries goes around 25000 then at that time pg_dump goes into crash condition. can you please try with that amount of entries? Please let me know the result as soon as possible.

Comment: We are also going to use 3.2.0 version which is latest release for PG and let you know the result...

Comment: @Jester, Please also try with 25000 entries and let us know the result you will get as quickly as possible...

Comment: I have postgres 9.2.4 on debian 64 bit, and it worked fine for a table with ~680k records.

Comment: @Jester, We will try with the version 9.2.4 that you are using with that amount of database entries and let you know the result as soon as possible.